# How can I bring box middle of the website without breaking header?

Tags: html, css

I have tried to fix a lot of time but I can't figure it out. I want to separate header (navbar) and box but when I use margin on the box, the header (navbar) move with the box, But I just want to margin the box only. The position of the header position should not be effected.

Here is my code:

```
.box {
  width: 450px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
margin-top: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: why not use position: fixed on header?

Comment: Can you include your HTML?